# Alert Box Making Selenium IDE fail on Firefox

Tags: selenium, iis, web-config, selenium-ide

[image]

From the image above I am looking for a way to:

1. Turn this message off so the dialog does not show for this error. Is there a configuration in IIS or Web.config that can turn this off or ignore the warning. Could this be certificate/ssl issue?
2. Allow Selenium to click on Continue button or suppress this dialog box

Answer (score 1):

1) You can try to make an https connection instead of http
or else

2) Try this create a new firefox profile with the security [preferences](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Security.) turned off and use that profile in your web driver initialization

```
security. warn_leaving_secure
security. warn_entering_weak
```